# Editting webRequest URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Is it possible to edit the URL of a webRequest (Using extension)? Here's how i'm attempting to do so-

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(function(info){
    info.url = info.url.replace("adblock=false","adblock=true");
    return {cancel:false};
},
{
    urls: ["*://somesitetoblock.com/*"],
    types: ["main_frame", "sub_frame", "stylesheet", "script", "image", "object", "xmlhttprequest", "other"]
},
["blocking"]);
```

Comment: So you want to try to work around a user's preference for ad blocking?

Comment: I'm developing an ad-block for pandora and no, I removed a lot of my script for simplicity purposes. I wanted to see if I could edit the jQuery data being sent to/from their server to the page to basically trick the web-player that an ad shouldn't be playing soon

Comment: @steve, if your problem is that i'm by-passing user preferences you should know that in my extension, users have the option of turning on/off all ad block tools

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Reading the documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest#type-BlockingResponse) is usually helpful.

```
return {redirectUrl: yourModifiedUrl};
```

Note that it's your responsibility to prevent any possible infinite loops - only do that if the URL was actually modified.